# Dealing with height of Angular component inside a flex container

Tags: angular, flexbox

I'd like to create a simple tabview component with the following requirements:

- It should take 100% of its parent container's height
- Each panel/tab has a header with a button to collapse/expand it and a content, which holds a treeview component, and should take all the remaining space of the panel
- If I collapse a panel, the expanded ones should grow proportionally

I've prepared an example on Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4pgdbj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

The problem I'm having is that the treeview components that are inside the panels doesn't take all the height, because the parent is a flex div. I'm pretty new to flex CSS rules, and I'd like to know if there's a way to force the height to 100% in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should set `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` on item containers. otherwise `flex: 1` on app-tree doesn't have any effect because it is not in a flex container. when they become flex containers with column layout, app-tree elements will take up remaining space.

here is a workig demo based on the stackblitz demo above.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqnxub

Comment: Hi! I'm almost sure that I tried something like this, but it's clear I missed something because it wasn't working. I'm giving it a try right now and I'll let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, not sure why you need Flexbox? As the div with Flex display, only has one child?
If you set a height of 100% on the flex display div, remove the flex display, and another 100% on the div inside the app-tree, it will solve your issue.

So, relevant code:

```
<div style="height: 100%" [ngStyle]="{ 'display': tabsExpanded[0] ? 'block' : 'none' }">
    <app-tree></app-tree>
</div>
```

and

```
<div style="background: #fca; height: 100%">
  <ul>
    <li>Sample li</li>
    <li>Second sample</li>
    <li>Third!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! If I remove the 'flex: 1' from the item container, the tabs aren't distributed evenly anymore. Anyway, I've read more about the Flexbox system and I think that it's not possible to achieve what I want. So, I'll calculate the appropriate heights of the divs using `ViewChild` and I'll update them when the container size is changed. I'll post the working solution when I get it. Cheers!

Comment: All good @fel! I can only recommend to follow a CSS course on Flexbox. I've been mucking and trialing & error for a long time, after following a course I understand it much better.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I couldn't make it work 100% as I needed with Flexbox, so I decided to create a simple custom accordion component that calculates the heights of the panels according to their collapsed/expanded status. Then, by handling the resize event of the window, I recalculate these heights whenever there's a change.

Thanks for all the suggestions!